# Relation between free action and free modules

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Consider $X$ some topological space with a **free** action by some group $G$, and denote by $C_\bullet(X)$ some chain complex associated to $X$ (the singular/simplicial one, say).

The action of $G$ on $X$ induces one on $C_\bullet(X)$, so we can view it as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module. Is it true that $C_\bullet(X)$ should be a **free** module over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$? As in, a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$?

I think it should be true, but I'm not really sure how to make the connection. I think it would be enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ freely permutes the generators of $C_\bullet(X)$, but I don't necessarily see why that should be true. It is not hard to produce examples where $G$ acts freely on $X$, but trivially on some simplices (for example, $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ by rotation by $\mathbb{2\pi}/3$); though that shouldn't necessarily be a counterexample because even then, the action is free on *most* simplices.

Anyway, any ideas are appreciated :)

---

*The reason I ask this:* I encountered in a paper the statement that for $G$ a cyclic group, $EG$ its total classifying space, then $C_\bullet(X\times EG)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generators of $C_n(X)$ are continuous maps from the $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ to $X$. If $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$ and $g\circ \sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$ is the same generator, then $g(\sigma(p))=\sigma(p)$ for all $p\in \Delta^n$, since your action is free $g=1_G$.

Comment: But what about the case where $\sigma$ is a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the action of $G = \mathbb{Z}_3$ is rotation by $\mathbb{2\pi}/3$? On some nice regular triangle, the action of $G$ is trivial on the simplex $\sigma$, but it is free on $\mathbb{R}^2$? How do we exclude this case from being a generator?

Comment: If my definitions are correct, then the image $g(\sigma)$ will be a different element in $C_*(\mathbb{R}^2)$ since $\sigma $ and $g(\sigma)$ will be different continuous maps, but yeah they have the same image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Let me go check my definitions haha, maybe that's why I'm confused. So, this would tell us that $G$ freely permutes the generators. Does it automatically tell us that $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ does, though? Because that's what we'd like, for $C_\bullet(X)$ to be a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ to be free, isn't it?

Comment: An element of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ doesn’t permute the generators, if you just look at $2*1_G$, it just maps $\sigma$ to $2\sigma$. Sadly I’m not that familiar with $G$-modules, but i guess if we denote the generators of $C_n(X)$ by $A$ then as we saw $G$ acts freely on $A$. Then choose an element from every orbit and this should be a free generator system of $C_n(X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module.

Comment: Alright, I think I see what you mean. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sure mate. I hope I didn’t say anything stupid. :)